# creating array in r of difference from df

Tags: r

So given the following columns, I need to create a new array that contains the difference between the columns for example with the sample below I need to create an array that contains the difference between the average one and two scores for each house by str, so far I have something like summarise(diff = abs(diff(one,two)), .groups = "drop") but its not quiet working out, any way i would go about this?

```
,,house = reg

str    one   two three 
reg    443    518  440
smol  342    587  432
regai   534    597  443

,,house = smol

str    one   two three 
reg    530    586  435
smol  541    597  447
regai   539    602  439
```

So like my ideal output look something like this not data frame an array that looks like:

```
str      reg    smol 
reg     440-518 435-586
smol   432-587  447-597
regai  443-597  439-602
```

So what I was thiking of doing was extracting each column create new column and make the difference, then at the end combine all the difference but the process would take too long so im trying to find shorter way. Also I need to make sure that the outputs are absolute values

update now im doing something like this:

diff = (abs(df$three - df$two))

Comment: Is it a list of data.frame or array?  Can you show the `dput` of the exampe. thanks

Comment: I'M also not sure if you really want to use the diff function. diff is not teh same as calculating the difference, so you maybe just want to do `abs(one - two)`.

Comment: Is your initial dataset `data.frame` ?

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
cbind(df1[1], setNames(lapply(list(df1, df2), 
         function(x) abs(x$three - x$two)), c('reg', 'smol')))
```

-output

```
#     str reg smol
#1   reg  78  151
#2  smol 155  150
#3 regai 154  163
```

---

If it an `array` created from `xtabs`, an option is also

```
out1 <- lapply(seq_len(dim(input_data)[3]), function(i) {

         x <- as.data.frame(input_data[,, i])
         abs(x$three - x$two)
         })
names(out1) <- c('reg', 'smol')
cbind(as.data.frame(input_data[,,1])[1]), out1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(str = c("reg", "smol", "regai"), one = c(443L, 
342L, 534L), two = c(518L, 587L, 597L), three = c(440L, 432L, 
443L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(str = c("reg", "smol", "regai"), one = c(530L, 
541L, 539L), two = c(586L, 597L, 602L), three = c(435L, 447L, 
439L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: This could work but what if the y arent individual data frames, they are both part of the same df created by using xtabs

Comment: @tyty Can you update your post with `dput(yourinputdata)` so that I get the structure correctly

Comment: @tyty I updated the post.  It is not tested though